# How to call some html javascript function at servlet that update that html content(java)

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

How to call some html javascript function at servlet that update that html content(java).

Can you please provide me the sample example.

**i have one server servlet that writes data that data need to update in another server html.is it possible?if so how?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about providing code to a non-attempted, non-question.

Comment: thank you.but is it possible at servlet to call html java script?

Comment: Why are you trying to call client side code on the server?

Comment: i need to update html page located at server webcontent so that reflects everywhere

Comment: I think you are approaching from the wrong side. Usually Client will invoke a request(ajax or non ajax) and based on response it will update the page.

Comment: i have to send data from another server servlet using HttpURLConnection to this servlet

Comment: i have one server servlet that writes data that data need to updated in another server html.is it possible?if so how?

Comment: i think what all you need to do is, from first servlet (after writing data) make a request to another servlet ( which is on another server )only. When another servlet will receive request, it is another servlet's responsiblity how to handle request and what to produce as result. You will get the result from another servlet in first servlet, and then your first servlet will be responsible for handling that result and producing result for request made by client to first servlet.

Comment: how to set that received data to html at that servlet

Comment: Usually data is provided in Json/Xml format. HTML format is to display data on browser, So if your another servlet is data-provider then it should send data in json/xml format. Take help of third party libs to parse json/xml. See my answer for details.

Comment: how to update some html div data at servlet

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion going above i think what you are looking for is something like following:

1. Client ---request--> First Servlet
2. First Servlet make some computation.
3. First Servlet ----request---> Another Servlet
4. First Servlet <--response--- Another Servlet
5. First servlet receives data from another servlet and parse the data. If it is data only, then it should be in Json/Xml format.
6. First servlet handles the parsed data and add it to its response.
7. Client <---response--- First Servlet

You can use third party libs for parsing the data received from Another Servlet.

Comment: 3 rd step should not happen .another server servlet push data to this servlet using HttpURLConnection with out request from 1st servlet.

Comment: Is that servlet is located on another server?

Comment: So to connect to another server, you need to make a request.

Comment: 2nd servlet push data using URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/Projectname/servletname?testData="+dateString);HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("string=");
out.close();